# Uploading image filename into textbox?

Tags: php, jquery

I have uploaded image filename into database and retrieved from database perfectly. Now i have a problem with updating that image filename. so, what I thought is getting the uploaded image name into textbox and storing that to database **so I need to get filename of uploaded image into textbox using php.**
Thanks in advance

Comment: you are saying that in edit...so you already wrote code for getting old data for edit...so get the image name value from there....but one thing you can not set default value inside file input.

Comment: yes i got that data but a user cannot remember image names so i thought of giving file type for uploading his new image, It works fine but when user does not want to upload new image and changes other fields and clicks on update button then an empty string is storing in database and removing the previous imageurl

Comment: see my answer that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you can do in the situaltion you mentioned in comment is.

Check for file input type value. if it posted black then store the hidden name from the form.

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="old_image" value="MySQL Query Old Result" />
<input type="file" name="image_url"  />
```

**PHP CHECKING**

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST['image_url']))
    {
        $save_image_to_db = $_POST['old_image'];
    }
    else
    {
        $save_image_to_db = $_POST['image_url']['name'];
    }

    //update query with $save_image_to_db
?>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion.I have already corrected this. The solution is similar to this